# Sort an array of rows alphabetically on a single column except one value must always be first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I am trying to sort an array of countries so that the row containing 'United States' (`id` 1) appears first, while every other country is sorted by alphabetical order.

How do I sort all EXCEPT United States to remain on top using the `usort()` function for an array?

Any alternative suggestions are also welcome. Here is my current code:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($countries->countries)) {
   $countries_array[] = array('id' => $key, 'text' => $value['countryname']);
}
function text_cmp($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a["text"], $b["text"]);
} 
usort($countries_array, 'text_cmp');
```

Comment: Do `array_shift` before sorting and `array_unshift` after.

Comment: @Andrew array_shift() would only work if United States was the first element, and array_unshift() would cause all the numerical keys to be lost/resorted.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you could re-key your array, then sort by keys, then merge the re-keyed array with an array with a lone US row, then re-index the array.  However, I don't recommend it because the number of iterations required in the process is unattractively high.  In other words, the time complexity is suboptimal.

```
$keyed = array_column($countries, null, 'text');
ksort($keyed);
var_export(array_values(['United States' => $keyed['United States']] + $keyed));
```

You could also call `array_search()` with `array_column()` isolating the `text` values, but are going to need to sort the column alphabetically anyhow.  So again, I'd rule that out for efficiency reasons.  I would also not recommend any approach using `in_array()`.

---

The truth is that this task can be accomplished with a single `usort()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cWLjH))

```
usort(
    $countries,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        [$a['text'] !== 'United States', $a['text']]
        <=>
        [$b['text'] !== 'United States', $b['text']]
);
var_export($countries);
```

By providing `$a` data on the left side of the spaceship operator and `$b` data on the right, ASC sorting is down.

Ascending sorting of boolean values puts `false` before `true`.  To ensure that the US row always has a higher priority than any other row, check if the `text` value is NOT `United States`.

The first element on each side of the spaceship operator is the first rule.  When both `text` values are not `United States`, then standard alphabetical sorting is applied.

This is a highly efficient approach because there are no iterated function calls.

---

Finally, because you are generating a new, specific array structure from the `countries` property of your `$countries` object inside of a loop, you could make better use of that loop. Maybe something like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($countries->countries as $id => ['countryname' => $text]) {
    $row = compact(['id' 'text']);
    if ($text === 'United States') {
        $result[] = $row;
    } else {
        $theRest[] = $row;
        $texts[] = $text;
    }
}
array_multisort($texts, $theRest);
array_push($result, ...$theRest);
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to remove the single value, sort and then re-add it:

[working example](https://eval.in/130315)

```
// your countries array goes here:
$countries = array(2=>"Burma", 4=>"Zimbabwe", 10=>"France", 1=>"United States", 13=>"Russia");

$AmericaFKYeah = array(1=>"United States");
$countries =array_diff($countries, $AmericaFKYeah);
asort($countries);

// using + instead of array_unshift() preserves numerical keys!
$countries= $AmericaFKYeah + $countries;
```

gives you:

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(13) "United States"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Burma"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "France"
  [13]=>
  string(6) "Russia"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "Zimbabwe"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm sort of a noob at this... how do I make a proper syntax for the USA array for the purpose of the array_diff if my countries array is a layered array? For example, I tried `USA = array('id' => 'USD', 'text'=> 'United States');` but this returns `Array ( [id] => USD [text] => United States )` and doesn't match with the countries array returning as `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => jp [text] => Japan ) [1] => Array ( [id] => USD [text] => United States )` ... etc

Comment: Your $countries_array seems unnecessarily complex. Is there a reason for all this? why not just `$countries_array[] = array($key=> $value['countryname']);`?

Comment: I think it's the way the OsCommerce engine is designed, as they use standardized this syntax so it can be re-used in other places... not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

### With Indexed Array

**Steps**

1. Find resource in array
2. Unset variable in array
3. Add resource as the first element in array with array_unshift (array_unshift — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

**Code**

```
 if (in_array('yourResource', $a_array)){
    unset($a_array[array_search('yourResource',$a_array)]);
    array_unshift($a_array, 'yourResource');
 }
```

### With MultiDimensional Arrays

```
$yourResorceToFind = 'yourResource';
foreach ($a_arrays as $a_sub_array){
  if (in_array($yourResorceToFind, $a_sub_array)){

    unset($a_arrays[array_search($yourResorceToFind,$a_sub_array)]);
    array_unshift($a_arrays, $a_sub_array);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: To add item at the end of arrays, use the push() method

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic trying to do the same thing in a ugly way but since my technique seems simpler I share it if someone needs.

The easiest way of doing it is by fiddling with the result of your usort callback. You just have to pass the value you want first in your callback like this :

```
$countries = [
 ['id' => 2, 'text' => 'Burma'],
 ['id' => 4, 'text' => 'Zimbabwe'],
 ['id' => 10, 'text' => 'France'],
 ['id' => 1, 'text' => 'United States'],
 ['id' => 13, 'text' => 'Russia'],
];

$myFirstItem = "United States";

usort($countries, function($a, $b) use ($myFirstItem) {
    return $myFirstItem == $a['text'] ? -1 : ($myFirstItem == $b['text'] ? 1 : strcmp($a['text'], $b['text']));
});
```

It's kind of ugly but does the job without the need to play with other arrays and everything is done in the callback, as expected.