# PHP sorting array of non-associative arrays but having string values at the beginning

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

```
 $unresponsives =   [
    [
        "Customer",
        "172.52.46.75",
        "2022-04-01 16:20:45",
        "1817",
        "nxlog",
        "2327.02 Hours"
    ],
    [
        "Customer",
        "172.25.89.45",
        "2022-04-01 16:20:45",
        "1817",
        "nxlog",
        "2327.02 Hours"
    ],
    [
        "Customer",
        "172.19.10.94",
        "2022-04-01 16:20:45",
        "1817",
        "nxlog",
        "2327.02 Hours"
    ]]
```

This is an example from my array of arrays. I want to sort the arrays inside by their fifth element (hours) in descending order. I am able to achieve this with usort but in the array there are also arrays with the string "Undefined" as their fifth value. Example below:

```
[
        "PreProd",
        "178.18.15.12",
        "\/",
        "1502",
        "iis",
        "Undefined"
    ]
```

Currently they are listed at the bottom of the array after the sorting is done. I instead want them to be listed in the beginning of the array. So first arrays with undefined ones and then the rest in descending order. How can I achieve this?

Below is the usort function that I use:

```
usort($unresponsives, function ($unresponsive1, $unresponsive2) {
            return floatval($unresponsive2[5]) <=> floatval($unresponsive1[5]);
        });
```

Comment: Add you expected output in question

Comment: Would also have been useful to provide the example with at least one of these `undefined` rows

Comment: Note "5th element" corresponds to index 4, as the former is an ordinal number and the latter an offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `array_multisort` Approach - Example https://3v4l.org/SuJQX

For a slightly more complex approach that allows fine-grained control of the sorting as desired. Use `array_column` to retrieve the hours. Use `array_keys` on the hours to determine the filtered value positions and iterate over the positions to assign them as a numeric value. Then `array_multisort` can be used with the desired flags to sort the resulting arrays.

```
$hours = array_column($unresponsives, 5);
if ($undefined = array_keys($hours, 'Undefined')) { 
    $hours = array_replace($hours, array_fill_keys($undefined, PHP_INT_MAX));
}
array_multisort($hours, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $unresponsives);
```

**Result**

```
var_export($unresponsives);

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => 'Undefined',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.25.89.45',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => 'Undefined',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.52.46.75',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2328.02 Hours',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2324.02 Hours',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2322.02 Hours',
  ),
)
```

**Ascending Numeric Sorting**

To change the sort order to `SORT_ASC` swap out `PHP_INT_MAX` for `PHP_INT_MIN`, depending on where in the array you want the filtered value to reside.

```
$hours = array_column($unresponsives, 5);
if ($undefined = array_keys($hours, 'Undefined')) {    
    $hours = array_replace($hours, array_fill_keys($undefined, PHP_INT_MIN));
}
array_multisort($hours, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $unresponsives);
```

**Result**

```
var_export($unresponsives);

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => 'Undefined',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.25.89.45',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => 'Undefined',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2322.02 Hours',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.19.10.94',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2324.02 Hours',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Customer',
    1 => '172.52.46.75',
    2 => '2022-04-01 16:20:45',
    3 => '1817',
    4 => 'nxlog',
    5 => '2328.02 Hours',
  ),
)
```

---

### `usort` Approach - Example https://3v4l.org/Uoml6

The same methodology of assigning the filtered value as a numeric value can be applied to `usort` by manipulating the compared values of the desired filtered value(s) in a conditional, which will only be used to sort the array.

**Descending Order**

```
function compd($a, $b)
{
    /*
    # Condensed Syntax
    return ('Undefined' === $b[5] ? PHP_INT_MAX : floatval($b[5])) <=> ('Undefined' === $a[5] ? PHP_INT_MAX : floatval($a[5]));
    */

     $v1 = $a[5];
     $v2 = $b[5];
     if ('Undefined' === $v1) {
         $v1 = PHP_INT_MAX;
     }
     if ('Undefined' === $v2) {
         $v2 = PHP_INT_MAX;
     }

     return floatval($v2) <=> floatval($v1);
}

usort($unresponsives, 'compd');
```

**Ascending Order**

As with the `array_multisort` approach change the sort order by swapping `PHP_INT_MAX` with `PHP_INT_MIN` but also swap the `$b[5] <=> $a[5]` comparison with `$a[5] <=> $b[5]` to sort the values in ascending order.

```
function compa($a, $b) 
{
    /*
    # Condensed Syntax
    return ('Undefined' === $a[5] ? PHP_INT_MIN : floatval($a[5])) <=> ('Undefined' === $b[5] ? PHP_INT_MIN : floatval($b[5]));
    */

     $v1 = $a[5];
     $v2 = $b[5];
     if ('Undefined' === $v1) {
         $v1 = PHP_INT_MIN;
     }
     if ('Undefined' === $v2) {
         $v2 = PHP_INT_MIN;
     }

     return floatval($v1) <=> floatval($v2);
}

usort($unresponsives, 'compa');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two steps.

1. Populate an array with ready-to-compare numeric values.
2. Call `array_multisort()` to compare in a DESC direction.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BGguO))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        fn($a) => sscanf($a[5], '%f')[0] ?? PHP_INT_MIN,
        $unresponsives
    ),
    SORT_DESC,
    $unresponsives
);
var_export($unresponsives);
```

---

This can also be performed with absolutely no iterated function calls for better efficiency.

The first rule checks for `Undefined` values and orders `true` evaluations before `false` evaluations.  The second rule is only applied when a tiebreaker is required -- in which case the float values are compared for a DESC sort direction.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Nh4uG))

```
usort(
    $unresponsives,
    fn($a, $b) => 
        [$b[5] === 'Undefined', (float) $b[5]]
        <=>
        [$a[5] === 'Undefined', (float) $a[5]]
);
var_export($unresponsives);
```

A similar approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72529525/2943403).

Comment: Not my downvote, realised you were correct and my code only worked on the data provided in the question.

Comment: Woops, you were right I uv'd the other answer when I intended to uv yours. I am really in need of a good long holiday

Answer (score -2):

Please have a look at bellow snippet

```
echo '<pre>';
function ShortFunction($new,$old){
    return floatval($old[5]) <=> floatval($new[5]);
}
$new_array = usort($unresponsives,'ShortFunction');
print_r($unresponsives);
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they miss an opportunity to educate/empower the asker and thousands of future researchers.